# Angular 2 How to get data passed by router in change event

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Below is sample of my route
`{ path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard], data: { title: 'Calendar' } },`

I want to get the data in router change event. Below is my event,

```
this._router.events
.filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized)
.subscribe((event: any) => {})
```

I am able to get data by following way,

`event.state._root.children[0].value._routeConfig.data`

I believe this is not a proper way to get data. **What is the proper way to get data here?**

---

Basically I want to set title of the page, so when I am in calendar page, my HTML page title should have 'Calendar'. I don't want this code to be done in every page. So I am making a general component which can take data from every route and change title of page.

**EDIT**

I can always get the data in component itself but that would be redundant. I will have to code in every component to set title. I want this exercise to be done in one place, so I am avoiding in component.

Comment: **just as an idea:**
you can use the `resolve` attribute in the router, so you create a Resolver which does the work with the title. But you have to add this attribut to every route. Or you use the `canActivate`-attribute for your route to set the title and simply return true for the routes https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Answer (score -1):

You can send data as an argument in the path. Then your route looks like this:

```
{ path: 'calendar/:title', component: CalendarComponent }
```

In the calendar component you can subscribe to this param like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    var title = params['title'];
    ...
  });
}
```

Your function will be called initially and every time the param changes.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I am avoiding this to be done in component.

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't get what you are doing exactly. Where do you get the `title` from? If you load it from the server or have in your app component you could just include it in your app component's template and see it everywhere.

Comment: This is static data, I want to set title of the page, so when I am in calendar page, my HTML page title should have 'Calendar'. I don't want this code to be done in every page. So I am making a general component which can take data from every route and change title of page.

Answer (score -1):

**For Angular 4+**

if you want to access the route custom data on child or lower level components for which you've defined the route custom data you can do the following in that component considering you're passing route custom data `data: {title: 'somedata'}`:

```
 public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
      console.log(route.snapshot.data['title']);
  }
```

**But**, if you want to access the route custom data **globally from a parent or upper level component** to access the change in the route custom data then you've to listen to router events particularly `RoutesRecognized` or `NavigationEnd` events. I'm gonna show two procedures with `AppComponent` with two events:

**First Approach:**

```
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.router
        .events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => {
          let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
          while (child) {
            if (child.firstChild) {
              child = child.firstChild;
            } else if (child.snapshot.data && child.snapshot.data['custom_data']) {
              return child.snapshot.data['custom_data'];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
          return null;
        }).subscribe( (customData: any) => {
          console.log(customData);
       });
    }
 }
```

**Second Approach is using:**

```
this.router.events
.filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized)
.map( (event: RoutesRecognized) => {
    return event.state.root.firstChild.data['custom_data'];
})
.subscribe(customData => {
    console.log(customData);
});
```

**Note:** Even though last one is shorter and usually works, but, if you have nested routes then it is encouraged to use the first one.